# GNU mailutils: How to encode '@' and '$' in mailbox patterns

Tags: urlencode

I am trying to access a remote mail server and output the number of messages in a mailbox using the mailutils program messages.

I run the program from a shell with:

```
messages --config-file=/path/to/file/mailutils.cfg
```

where mailutils.cfg contains

```
mailbox {
  mailbox-pattern imaps://xxx@yyy.de:pass$word@imap.servername.de/INBOX;
}
```

and xxx@yyy.de is a user name that cannot be altered
and pass$word is a password that cannot be altered either.

I am geting a German error message which translated to English would be something like:

```
messages: mailbox could not be created: port and service invalid
```

When I run the program on an imap mailbox (not imaps) for an easier user/password combination everything works fine. So I conclude mailutils does not like the '$' in the password and/or the '@' in the user name.

When I run messages for a user xxx@yyy.de with a simple password abcd using the '%40' encoding for the @ sign

```
mailbox {
  mailbox-pattern imaps://xxx%40yyy.de:abcd@imap.servername.de/INBOX;
}
```

I get the error message 'verstreutes Zeichen %' which probably means something like `'found infeasible character %'`.

So: how to encode '@' and '$' in mailutils?
I may be blind but the manual does not tell how do solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, put the pattern into double quotes (Gänsefüßchen)

```
mailbox-pattern "imaps://xxx%40yyy.de:abcd@imap.servername.de/INBOX";
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the Gänsefüßchen did it. Referring to my original question:
`   mailbox {
     mailbox-pattern "imaps://xxx%40yy.de:pass%24word@imap.servername.de/INBOX";
     }`